# Implementing heap sort algorithm in Python receiving recursion error when running

Tags: python, recursion, heapsort, recursionerror

Im trying to implement the heap sort algorithm to sort a list but receiving the following error code:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Please let me know if you find any issues I will post my functions and helper functions below as follows:

```
def heap_sort(A):
    heap_size = _build_max_heap(A)
    for i in range(heap_size // 2, -1):
        A[0], A[i] = A[i],A[0]
        heap_size = heap_size - 1
        _max_heapify(A,heap_size, I)

def _build_max_heap(A):
    heap_size = len(A)
    for i in range(heap_size // 2):
        _max_heapify(A,heap_size, I)
    return heap_size

def _left(I):
    return (2*i)+1

def _right(i):
    return (2*i)+2

def _max_heapify(A, heap_size, i ):
     l = _left(i)
    r = _right(i)
    if l < heap_size and A[i] < A[l]:
        largest = l
    else:
        largest = i
    if r < heap_size and A[largest] < A[r]:
        largest = r
    if largest != i:
       A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
    _max_heapify(A,heap_size, largest)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is due to the fact that your `_max_heapify` function calls itself recursively, and it ALWAYS calls itself, no matter what is passed to it as parameters.  For recursion to work, there has to be a condition that becomes true such that the recursive function doesn't call itself.  You need to modify your logic so that this is the case...so that there is some condition that at some point halts the recursion by having an execution of `_max_heapify` that doesn't call itself.

Comment: Considering this, does the rest of my implementation look correct and once I figure out how to fix this issue, does my algorithm look like it will efficiently run? Also, is there anyway you can go into further depth specifying how I can go about making this change, I am relatively new to coding and recursion is not my strong suit.

Comment: Well, your code has some syntax errors in it (see 'I' vs 'i'), so I wonder how you could have even gotten to the point where you got the recursion error.  I see some big red flags in your code.  For example, I don't understand why your `heap_sort` function calls `_build_max_heap`, which in terms calls `_max_heapify` a bunch of times, and then loops again, itself calling `_max_heapify` a bunch of times.  I can't imagine how going through the looping and recursion twice can be the right thing to do.